# Getting last known location from Google Play Services while device location is off

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location

I'm using `FusedLocationApi` to get device's last known location from Google Play Services.
My understanding is that `getLastLocation` delivers the last known location (assuming the needed permissions are granted) regardless of which app has requested the location even when the device location is off but does not work as such.

When the location is on it works as expected; But when it's off it returns `null` though it has previously retrieved the location for example from the `Google Maps` app.

Should it work like this or something's amiss here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you turn off a location provider on the device (GPS, Network, etc), it clears the last known location. Any apps that still shows a point of some kind when location is turned off probably cached it.

So the answer is that you should receive `null` for `getLastLocation` if location services is turned off.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the case.